# insert null value as interpolated parameter in query

Tags: c#, .net, dapper, xunit

I am trying to build a simple test with xUnit by using **InlineData**:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(null, "Message")]
public void MyTest(object value, string message)
{
    var insertQuery = $@"INSERT INTO {_MyTable} (
                            [MyId]
                        ) VALUES (
                            {value}
                        );";

    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        connection.Execute(query);
    }
}
```

I really want to insert the value **NULL** but when executing it complains:

> 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.'

And indeed if I go check the query it looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (
        [MyId]
    ) VALUES (
        
    );
```

so there interpolated parameter is not inserted correctly in the query. How can I do that? Thank you!

Comment: This would be fixed by using parameterised queries, as you should be doing anyway for good practice and security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've tagged this [dapper](/questions/tagged/dapper), basically: *don't* use interpolated strings; that's *not how it is meant to work*. Instead:

```cs
using var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
connection.Execute(@"
INSERT INTO TableNameThisShouldBeAConstant ([MyId])
VALUES (@value);", new { value });
```

Note that `value` here would ideally be well-typed as a string/int/etc.

Comment: I tried that approach and the result is: "'Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to nvarchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.".
(when I try to insert the NULL value directly in SSMS there is no problem)

Comment: @Tarta and did you change the type of `value` as I suggested, or did you leave it as `object`? tip: if you don't know the table name and the type of value in advance: you're not doing it right

Comment: My apologies Marc, I didn't understand that for well-type you meant strongly-typed and indeed luckily I know in advance the type of value. Hence by setting it properly it works! Thanks a lot :)